# CRITICAL neutron [-] Unhandled error: neutron.privileged.agent.linux.ip_lib.InterfaceOperationNotSupported Openstack

Tags: ubuntu, openstack, openstack-nova, openstack-neutron, openstack-glance

As per OpenStack nice documentation, I configure the neutron minimal setup with the "**self-service network**" option. when all configurations done i see the verify command "**openstack network agent list**" output not showing linuxbridge. then check the log file and see the error found.

2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 CRITICAL neutron [-] Unhandled error: neutron.privileged.agent.linux.ip_lib.InterfaceOperationNotSupported: Operation not supported on interface vxlan-4330, namespace None.
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/bin/neutron-linuxbridge-agent", line 10, in 
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     sys.exit(main())
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron/cmd/eventlet/plugins/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 28, in main
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     agent_main.main()
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 1039, in main
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     manager = LinuxBridgeManager(bridge_mappings, interface_mappings)
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 92, in **init**
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     self.check_vxlan_support()
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 729, in check_vxlan_support
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     if self.vxlan_ucast_supported():
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 705, in vxlan_ucast_supported
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     self.delete_interface(test_iface)
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron/plugins/ml2/drivers/linuxbridge/agent/linuxbridge_neutron_agent.py", line 670, in delete_interface
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     device.link.delete()
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/neutron/agent/linux/ip_lib.py", line 482, in delete
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     privileged.delete_interface(self.name, self._parent.namespace)
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_privsep/priv_context.py", line 271, in _wrap
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     return self.channel.remote_call(name, args, kwargs,
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oslo_privsep/daemon.py", line 215, in remote_call
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron     raise exc_type(*result[2])
2023-04-06 11:34:36.731 2553631 ERROR neutron neutron.privileged.agent.linux.ip_lib.InterfaceOperationNotSupported: Operation not supported on interface vxlan-4330, namespace None.

please help if you have any solution.

Comment: The term "vxlan" points to openvswitch, not linuxbridge. Please add your neutron config to the question and use appropriate code tags to make it readable.

Comment: Thank you for your help. As per your instruction, I am configuring the openvswitch. Almost all configuration is done  when I create an instance in the build section found another error (**Instance failed to spawn: neutronclient.common.exceptions.Unauthorized: Unknown auth type: None**)

Comment: Check your config file again, auth type means you don’t have a value set (probably), usually it’s „password“. It looks like you should double or triple check your configuration files for consistency.